# took it off the table, that would be a major advance

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand the logic of the phrase "took the problem of yet another emerging pandemic coronavirus off the table, that would be a major advance."  Usually "take something off the table" means "take it from consideration or discussion" or "ignore it". But here it seems to mean "solve the problem of another emerging pandemic" (thus make a major advance - while ignoring it would not be counted as a major advance).

What doee the phrase mean here?

> What about a broad-spectrum agent against viral illnesses, almost like an antibiotic?

> If you’re talking about an antiviral that protects against all viruses, then I think that’s a bridge too far. But you could get a broad-spectrum antiviral that will be good against all strains of coronaviruses and then maybe a different one that works within another family of viruses. An antiviral that worked against any manner or form of coronaviruses would be highly desirable. If we **took the problem of yet another emerging pandemic coronavirus off the table, that would be a major advance.**

Source:   [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fauci-explains-how-to-end-the-covid-pandemic/)

December 14, 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, American and Canadian usage is different. In US, to put an issue "on the table" is to discuss it. To take it "off the table" is to defer it.

But, to "table" the discussion in US English means to defer it, while to "table" the discussion in Canadian English means to discuss the matter presently.

So, "if we stopped worrying about other viral plagues, that would be a step forward."

Comment: That is, Fauci meant that concentrating our energy and resources in solving the current crisis and stopping worrying about the next pandemic would be a major advance (because doing too much is often the equivalence of doing nothing)?                                         
        Thank you.